# How to assign a variable to an query result

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

How do I assign the query result to a variable.

I am using SQLlite. Below is the code for retrieving password from the User Table. I need to compare the given password and the given password.

```
    Dim i As String
    Dim p As String
    i = txtUserID.Text
    p = txtPassword.Text

    Try
        Dim sqlConnection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
        Dim sqlCommand As New SQLiteCommand("", sqlConnection)
        Dim sqlPath As String = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\SimpleDB.db3"
        Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT Password FROM User WHERE UserID LIKE '" & i & "'"
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = sqlPath
        sqlConnection.Open()
        sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid ID or Password. Please try again.")
    End Try
```

***Edit 1***:

In this below code why do I need to use GetInt16(0). Why 16 and why 0 in the parameter. What is difference between GetInt32() , GetInt16() and GetString()

```
DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int id=  reader.GetInt16(0);
}
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are using `sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` - this will only return the number of row affected.

Use a different method - something that will return the results, for example:

```
sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

You need to assign the returned value of this to a variable of type [`DbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.aspx) (or rather the [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) that inherits from it).

This will give you a `SqlDataReader` that you can iterate over in order to retrieve values.

Comment: @Failed_Noob - Sir, how about you follow the links I provided, read the documentation (which has examples), and learn for yourself?

Comment: DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

   ` while (reader.Read())
    {
        int id=  reader.GetInt16(0);
    }

    reader.Close();` In this why do we need to specify it as GetInt16(0)

Comment: @Failed_Noob - Why are you asking as a comment to my answer? Ask a new question (not before searching the rest of StackOverflow - this was probably asked before).